# Subprocess.call() and gunzip error

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to use Python's package subprocess to gunzip and gzip files. 
I'm using the following command:

```
subprocess.call(['gunzip', a_path+myfile_gz], shell=True)
```

Then I get the error message:

> gzip: compressed data not read from a terminal. Use -f to force decompression.

So I typed:

```
subprocess.call(['gunzip', '-f', a_path+myfile_gz], shell=True)
```

And I get exactly the same error message.
If I type `shell=False`, it's worse.

It's really weird because if I do it from my terminal, it works fine!
Does anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: Show us the complete call, like `" ".join(['gunzip', a_path+myfile_gz])`

Comment: Why don't you use the gzip package? It's in the standard library.

Comment: What errors do you get when you use `shell=False`? It works for me when I do that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing `shell=True`, so you're executing

```
sh -c gunzip /path/to/file.gz
```

(assuming `a_path+myfile_gz` is `"/path/to/file.gz"`). In other words, because the `shell` parameter is `True`, the first element of the command list is a shell snippet; the other arguments are arguments to that shell snippet (here just `$0`). This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

If you leave out `shell=True`, you'll get working but not good code. Don't manipulate paths as strings; use the functions in the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html). That `a_path+myfile_gz` should probably be `os.path.join(a_path, myfile_gz)` instead.

In any case, Python has built-in support for [gzip](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html). Don't use an external command.

Comment: "Don't use an external command": unless you [care about speed](https://codebright.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/139/)